# Civivolunteer on mobile

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer

I am using Civivolunteer on wordpress. Works good, except on smartphones. The shopping card comes in front of the signup checkbox, so users can't sign up. Anyone having the same problem, or is it because of my wordpress site?

[image: horizontal][image: vertical]
can't scroll right to the checkbox in vertical position

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have a screenshot of what it looks like? It sounds like something in your theme or stylesheet is causing this to happen. In my Drupal site, I have styles that are used only on the mobile version of our site so that we could make it even more user-friendly.

Comment: That'd be my guess. Civi's styling isn't too adaptive for small screens. Someone with CiviVolunteer would have to check the css to see what's getting in the way of adaptive styling.